# Sharepoint 2010 cascading menu help

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

Attempting to build a cascading menu in SharePoint 2010, using info path.  Basically I have 3 menus as shown below.  All 3 menus are tied to a sharepoint list of info. – when I select that, menu 2 populates based on an infopath filter/data source I set using this link and it works fine!  Each would populate on the prior level.

What I'm trying to do now is populate a third menu, based on info in the 2nd menu.  No matter which way I try and filter it, its blank.  Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created four lists for the relationship structure, then you can filter the 3rd menu like the 2nd menu.

In addition, you can also achieve it using jQuery.

[Reference for you](http://sharepoint713.blogspot.sg/2011/09/multilevel-cascading-dropdown-in.html).

Comment: Yep I have 4 lists for the relationship.  Would rather do this with InfoPath versus jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

2/3 of my lookup lists were using lookup columns, in the 3rd list, for some reason I typed everything in manual, versus using a lookup.  Well the InfoPath formula filter didn't like that.  Once I redid the list using column lookups versus manual entries, it worked!